# Extracting the second last string between two semi-colons

Tags: sql-server

I have a field in the following format: 'xyz;123;abc' or '456;bcd' and would like to extract just the second last string between the ';'s. In these example, I want the new column to be '123' and '456'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a comma-separated value to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns)

Comment: If you are lucky to be using SQL Server 2016 then you can simply use SPLIT()

Comment: @RossBush STRING_SPLIT doesn't work as op wants

Comment: If you use a splitter I would strongly advise you NOT to use the one from the accepted answer in the proposed duplicate. Looping is not needed for splitting strings. But honestly a splitter seems excessive here.

Comment: @RossBush it's `STRING_SPLIT`, however, that won't help; the function doesn't provide oridinal position. Personally I recommend [DelimitedSplit8k](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/), or [DelimtiedSplit8K_LEAD](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQL+Server+2012/106903/) if you're on SQL Server 2012+ if you need a string splitter, and need to retain or (reliably) retain the order of the items.

Comment: @Lamak - Thanks for the update.

Comment: @Larnu - I could not find the link, however, there is a widely read article comparing the fastest string split functions. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you always have at least two values you can use [PARSENAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for this which is a lot simpler than a string splitter or complicated string manipulation.

```
declare @Something table
(
    SomeVal varchar(20)
)

insert @Something values
('xyz;123;abc')
, ('456;bcd')

select *
    , parsename(replace(s.SomeVal, ';', '.'), 2)
from @Something s
```

Comment: yes, `parsename` is the way to go if the string follows op's format

Answer (score 1):

reverse the string, find the first and second `;` and you got the string you want. Just reverse again to get it in the right order

```
; with tbl as
(
    select  field = 'xyz;123;abc'   union all
    select  field = '456;bcd'
)
select  *, new_col = reverse(substring(reverse(field), idx1 + 1, idx2 - idx1 - 1))
from    tbl t
    cross apply
    (
        select  idx1 = charindex(';', reverse(field))
    ) s1
    cross apply
    (
        select  idx2 = charindex(';', reverse(field) + ';', idx1 + 1)
    ) s2
```